# Error agregando controlador de tabla Azure - HRESULT E_FAIL

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2017

Buen día,

Al tratar de agregar un controlador de tabla de aplicaciones moviles de Azure, me sale el siguiente error:

Error al ejecutar el generador de códigos seleccionado: "Devuelto error HRESULT E_FAIL de una llamada a un componente COM"

Estoy usando Visual Studio 2017 15.3.3

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradecería su colaboración tratando de solucionar este inconveniente.

Saludos

Comment: Agregar el ensamblado System.Data a las referencias del proyecto soluciona el problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bug solucionado en la nueva version de Visual Studio 15.4.1
[image: Bug Resuelto]